# MoBo Post Test - GPU & Integrated Graphics

Tags: motherboard, post

I am building my first PC. I have all the parts and have been advised to perform a power-on self-test (POST) test before installing the MoBo into the case.

I am using a MSI Krait Edition Z97S mobo and an Intel i5-4690k. Of course I will also mount the CPU cooler and plug the PSU in.

My question is, do I have to also plug in my graphics card? Or with this setup, can I just plug the HDMI from the monitor into the appropriate Mobo I/O port? It just seems that it would be easier to do if I could wait to plug in the GPU till it is in the case.

Comment: You follow the installation instructions that come with the GPU.  But your GPU is an iGPU since you made no mention of an external GPU

Comment: My mistake, yes I have an external GPU (video card). I want to avoid plugging it in for the POST test if I can manage that. So I guess the CPU or motherboard (I'm not sure which) has some sort of onboard/integrated graphcis that will suffice for the post test?

Comment: Why don't you want to install the GPU? Yes; Your CPU has an iGPU

Comment: I plan to install the GPU when I mount the MoBo in the case proper. For the POST test it will be outside the case with minimal components installed just to perform the POST test. But thank you for answering my question :)